# UITableView scrolling is choppy in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, simulator

Here is a video with logging the index path in cell for row at index path: (see new link below)

So, another weird one... 
On my home iMac (brand new), when I run an Xcode project in the simulator for the first time, it runs fine.  If I then quit out of the simulator and Xcode and then open up Xcode again and run it - (think of this as starting to work on the project again another day) - When I attempt to scroll any uitableview, the simulator redraws ALL the cells (it doesn't seem to dequeue and reuse correctly). I know this because I am running NSLog when the cell is being drawn.

If I reset the setting in the simulator and then run it again - it scrolls smoothly.
I've tried completely uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling it to no avail.
I'm using Xcode 4.3.2.

Now, one might assume that this is something with the code BUT, get this:
I have another (brand new iMac) at the office. I have this Xcode project on dropbox so both copies are the same (office and home).  In the office, I do NOT have this weird scrolling problem... everything works correctly.

The only difference between the two macs (both are 27 inch and have 16gb RAM) is the hdd -
The office mac has a 1tb 7200 RPM drive. My home mac has an SSD from Apple.

I have no clue what could be causing this... It's REALLY frustrating.
I'm not against wiping my home mac and starting over but that's a bit drastic.

Thoughts?  I didn't post code because running the same code on 2 different computers yields different results, so the code doesn't seem to be the issue.

UPDATING WITH CODE -  and video http://ge.tt/4ZuZ9mI/v/0

```
       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"dateCell";

            FEDateCell *cell = (FEDateCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FEDateCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = dateCell; 
                [cell setClipsToBounds:YES];
            }
            PFObject *eventObj = [self.itemsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            //Get cell date from row
            NSDate *currentDate = [eventObj objectForKey:@"startDate"];

            cell.cellDate = currentDate;
            cell.eventsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:eventObj];

            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
            cell.dayNumber.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:cell.cellDate];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
            cell.dayName.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:cell.cellDate];


            [cell updateCellData];

            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: Some computers handle scrolling better than others... or maybe you have many apps running at the same time on your home iMac (i.e. VM page swaps) and none but your app on your work iMac. I still think you should post your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" code, which would show what you're doing for dequeue and cell creation.

Comment: clean and rebuild doesn't fix it.  I literally have to reset the simulator settings to get scrolling to work... it's incredibly frustrating.

Comment: Here's a video - http://ge.tt/4ZuZ9mI/v/0

Comment: Does this happen with the project if it is not on Dropbox? I have heard of strange behavior when mixing xcode projects and dropbox.

Comment: Good Question.  I'll move the project out of Dropbox when I get home.  Although, the weird thing is that it works fine on the office computer (same codebase from dropbox).

Comment: It still happens if it is not in dropbox...

Comment: Here is a video with logging the index path in cell for row at index path: http://ge.tt/3b23RqI/v/0

Comment: hi @dcinzona , TBC did you try THIS solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much deliberation, I decided to completely wipe the iMac and do a clean install.
Now, while I JUST performed the clean install (which, in affect, would be the same as resetting the content and settings in iOS simulator) - it appears that the issue has gone away.  Now, I'm not certain of this as I just performed the clean install, but again, I have closed and reopened Xcode multiple times, rebooted a few times and the issue has not returned.

REALLY annoying that it came to formatting the system and starting from scratch, but whatever.  At least it's working.

Comment: I can confirm that a clean install of the OS resolved the issue.  Several days of coding back and forth and no problems.  Looks like there was some kind of weird bug in the imaging process over at Apple.  Anyway, all resolved.

Comment: **Astounding** thanks for this report, @dcinzona. To be clear WAS IT ONLY CHOPPY ON THE iPHONE6 SIMULATOR? ON ON ALL?  Would really like to know, thanks again!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If things happen the way you described, consider [reporting](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug to Apple.

Comment: Yeah, I might do that now.  I'll post a video of it happening too.

Comment: I sent in a bug report to Apple, although after trying a couple of other "dropboxed" projects, I noticed that tableviews scroll fine (although I don't have any other projects with incredibly large tableviews so I might just create one and see if the issue continues.  If it doesn't I'm looking at a code problem that only seems to affect the simulator on one of my computers... The project runs totally fine on all of my test devices.

Comment: Link to bug report: (https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/57/wo/c1stvVx2wniL3VfVFYdbF0/8.66)

Comment: @dcinzona i can't access your report with this link. It would be helpful if you try to make a copy of the project, leave only the required code to reproduce the problem and somehow attach this project to the report, otherwise it would be difficult for Apple engineers to analyze the problem. You will also want to import the system information to `.spx` file with `System Information` app (File->Save), among the other info this will contain some Xcode/Simulator-SDK info.

Comment: @Joe Blow, 1. comment on the question, not an answer. 2. the second link is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try install a latest version of graphics card driver

Comment: Try recompile at another SDK. E.g. at 10.6

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information here to determine what the problem is. I think the best way forward would be for you to use the Xcode profiling tools to track down where the problem might be. Also look at the graphical profiling tools to determine if excessive drawing is happening.

Comment: Check out this document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6-SW17